# Creating thumbnails of a grid/WrapPanel or other UIElement in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, grid, thumbnails, uielement

I have a `Grid` with some `Image`s.

I want to make another `Grid` that will be copy of this `Grid`, 'only smaller'.  I want every `Image` I will add to the first `Grid` will add also to the other `Grid`.

If someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVVM you have a binding that drives the first grid's contents. Rebind the second grid to the same data member and it will update to show the same contents even after edits were performed on that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use VisualBrush

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <StackPanel Name="Original" Width="100" Height="100">
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Pretend I'm a list of images"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Name="Thumbnail" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Original}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</UniformGrid>
</Page>
```